# What is the name of this experimental OS?

Tags: operating-systems, communication-protocols

I am trying to find an OS that had a network to verify it's users.  It classified itself in classes going from greatest signifigance to least, and the names were galaxy, system, planet, comet etc.

I can not find the name of this OS or protocol for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an operating system called ( Urbit OS / Arvo )

https://github.com/urbit/urbit

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to clarify how it meets the requirements?  Does it classify itself in classes, and what's that, and what names did it use?  In what sense does it have a network to verify its users?

Comment: @D.W. The post just ask for the name of the operating system

Comment: We're generally looking for answers that support their claims with explanation, analysis, or other details.

Comment: Urbit IDs come in three classes: galaxies, stars, and planets. The length of an identity’s name will tell you its class. Galaxies are 8-bit and have names like ~mul. Galaxies issue 16-bit stars (~dacmul), which can themselves issue 32-bit planets (~laptel-holfur). Source: https://urbit.org/faq